# JavaFX components inside HTML?

Tags: java, html, javafx-2, javafx

Is it possible to put `JavaFX` components inside `HTML`?

For example, I have a file .html, and a div to put a `JavaFX button`, I know it's not very logical but it is possible I would like to know.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.

take a look at "Deployment in the Browser":
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deployment_toolkit.htm

Answer (score 1):

[Orochi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18198844/1263583) gives you the first part of your question: how to embed JavaFx in the browser.

> For example, I have a file .html, and a div to put a JavaFX button, I
>   know it's not very logical but it is possible I would like to know.

For this part, you'll need to integrate JavaFx with the html. I'd suggest you to load the html in a WebView, and draw your button on top of that.

You could even do some exotic things like parse the DOM to get your div and dynamically draw your JavaFx button on top of it depending on some properties contained in the div.

I'm not sure it would be really efficient though.

Comment: This is what we need, though ... I did not perfectly